# Sublist choices change based on choice made in first list

Tags: list

I'm looking to see if something like this is possible - essentially using some jump logic.

The request is to create a list using some of the standard columns, but also some custom ones. Where it's getting tricky is the request for some jump logic based on the user's selection of  a pre-populated list.

Eg.
Column 1:
Fruit
Veggies
Cheese

If you picked Fruit in column 1, column 2 would display Apples, Oranges, Bananas to choose from. If you picked Veggies in column 1, column 2 would display Carrots, Onions, Celery.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to hard code the fuctionality into the field itself, or just to control the rendering of the edit form?  Options below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns) function in my [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) jQuery library.  I think it does exactly what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using SharePoint 2007? If you want to achieve the above scenario, you could do so by coding a custom field type that had this parent-child behaviour baked in.

I have already seen several examples of this, and used one of them to code my own flavor of it.

Examples of something similar on codeplex:

[SharePoint Cascading Drop Down List (With Filter) Field Type](http://cascddlistwithfilter.codeplex.com/)

[Sharepoint - Query Based Lookup Field Control](http://customfieldcontrols.codeplex.com/)

[MSDN: How to create a custom field control.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981226.aspx)